# Intellij: `docker-compose up` on individual test run?

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea, docker-compose, spock

I can't use the play button to run an individual test in Intellij<sup>1</sup>, because our integration tests require mongo to be running, but I *can* use the `Gradle` tab to run all integration tests, because we have the following in our `build.gradle`:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

// ...

dockerCompose.isRequiredBy(integrationTest)

dockerCompose {
    useComposeFiles = [rootProject.file('src/test/resources/compose.yml').absolutePath]
    executable = '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
    dockerExecutable = '/usr/local/bin/docker'
}
```

How can I get an individual test to first `docker-compose up` when I'm running it from Intellij?

[1]: Unless I've started docker-compose manually from the terminal, being careful to use the one in `src/test/resources` rather than the one in `src/main/resources`, because they point to two different databases, and the tests clear out the test db, I think.